# Separate each number using “;” every 8 digits in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

All,
I have a data frame looks something like this :

```
Column A : X , Y
Column B : 123456781234567812345678,123456781234567812345678
```

The goal is to use pandas such that I can split Column B every 8 characters with “;” between numbers.

Final output should like this:

```
Column A : X ,Y
Column B : 12345678;12345678;12345678
,12345678;12345678;12345678
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas ?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: it's unclear if, in your example, the output should have 1 or 3 rows

Comment: So just a single row but with splits ;,

Comment: I want to have the same row just want to add the splits

Comment: Probably convert the into to a string and add ';' every 8 chars.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
# example input
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', 'Y'],
                   'B': [123456781234567812345678,
                         123456781234567812345678]})

df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str).str.replace(r'(\d{8})(?<!$)', r'\1;', regex=True)
```

output (as new column B2 for clarity):

```
   A                         B                          B2
0  X  123456781234567812345678  12345678;12345678;12345678
1  Y  123456781234567812345678  12345678;12345678;12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.T.loc[:,0].map(lambda x:";".join([x[i:i+8] for i in range(0,len(x),8)]))
```

out

```
X     12345678;12345678;12345678
 Y    12345678;12345678;12345678
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.